# Selection Sum - Javascript

Tags: javascript, data-structures

If I have an array of object like this one:

```
obj = [{id:1,value:2},{id:1,value:3},{id:2,value:8}]
```

How can I sum the values with the same id and return another array with the totals of each index?

Comment: Array reduce.........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reduce to achieve that

```js
const obj = [{
  id: 1,
  value: 2
}, {
  id: 1,
  value: 3
}, {
  id: 2,
  value: 8
}, {
  id: 3,
  value: 4
}, {
  id: 2,
  value: 1
}]

const result = Object.values(
  obj.reduce((a, { id, value }) => (((a[id] ??= { id, value: 0 }).value += value), a), {})
);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: can you  explain? I dont get at all....